# raspi5 23.10 cannot switch to lightdm from gdm3

Tags: lightdm, 23.10

I've installed 23.10 on a Raspberry Pi 5 and it all seems groovy.

The default display manager is gdm3, in line with the 23.10 current blessed GUI with the bar on the left and so on.  (I don't know what that UI is called; I don't like it.)

Thus, I'm trying to switch to the usual xubuntu stuff I've used on all my other systems for the past many years.

Everything seemed to be fine.  I could work through Synaptic and install all the usual components.  As long as I don't switch to lightdm, which I need to get to the UI I like.

If, when all is healthy in the unwanted UI, I concoct a terminal window and type

> sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm

it offers the expected choice.  If I choose lightdm and reboot, I get a full (I think; maybe VGA) resolution graphics mode dialog box that says

> ! The system is running in low-graphics mode   Your screen, graphics
> card, and input device settings   could not be detected correctly.
> You will need to configure these yourself.

If I poke OK, it goes through a series of dialogs offering things like Reconfigure graphics, Troubleshoot the error, and so on, none of which lead to anything actually useful.

If I switch to another console with Ctrl-Alt F3 (for example) I can switch back to gdm3 and after a reboot, all is back to the undesired UI.

Looking at /var/log/Xorg.0.log, it ends with

> [   147.052]  ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 25.2 [   147.052]
> (II) FBDEV(0): using default device [   147.064] (II) modeset(G0):
> using drv /dev/dri/card1 [   147.065] (WW) VGA arbiter: cannot open
> kernel arbiter, no multi-card support [   147.065] (EE)  Fatal server
> error: [   147.0! The system is running in low-graphics mode   Your screen, graphics card, and input device settings   could not be detected correctly.  You will need to configure these yourself.65] (EE) Cannot run in framebuffer mode. Please
> specify busIDs        for all framebuffer devices [   147.065] (EE)  [
> 147.065] (EE)  Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support     at http://wiki.x.org  for help.  [   147.065] (EE) Please also check the
> log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information. [
> 147.065] (EE)  [   147.116] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.

It appears that whatever the rpi5 has for graphics is not known well enough by 23.10 to run lightdm.

I't been 30 years since I tried to chase an X Window System startup problem, so it is gobbledy-gook to me.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The Raspberry Pi 5 is missing the required configuration for X11.](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?p=2159161). Let's add it by pasting the following into a new `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/99-vc4.conf` file:

```
Section "OutputClass"
  Identifier "vc4"
  MatchDriver "vc4"
  Driver "modesetting"
  Option "PrimaryGPU" "true"
EndSection
```

Comment: Wow.That just fixed it.  It should all be that easy.

Comment: I see that's asking for (some variation of?) the drm/vc4 Broadcom VC4 Graphics Driver.  Or so I surmise.

Comment: (I keep hitting cr and ending the message.)
If I take this pile of bits nd put it on an 8GB rpi4, it just works, without the wonderful addition that fixed it for the rpi5.
How come?

Comment: Thank you so very much.

Comment: @bog I suppose it's because they released the rpi4 with X11 in mind, but once they switched to Wayland, they didn't bother to add it when they released the rpi5. Btw, on AskUbuntu we usually press the "accept answer" button instead of saying thanks

Comment: FYI...
I took the 1tb uSD and 4tb WD USB drive and plopped it onto an rpi4 (actually an rpi400 kb computer; previous experience has shown no difference from the rpi4) and, again, it Just Worked.

I imagine that file will work its way into an upcoming release?  Or maybe an Xubuntu release -- my current favorite.

Again, thank you very much for the help.

Comment: @bog I'm not sure. The Raspberry Pi foundation doesn't seem to be focused on X11 anymore, so you should go to their forums and send them feedback. Saying "thank you very much for the help" is not allowed on AskUbuntu, so please do https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/1373352 instead

Comment: Er... Don't see an "Accept Answer" button.  Of course my eyes aren't so good...

Comment: Suddenly the check mark appeared.  So Check.